# Scan a directory and transfer files

Tags: python

I think that's easy but my script doesn't work. I think it's gonna be easier if I show you what I want: I want a script (in python) which does that:

I have a directory like:

```
boite_noire/
....helloworld/
....test1.txt/
....test2.txt/
```

And after running the script I would like something like:

```
boite_noire/
helloworld/
....test1/
........test1_date.txt
....test2/
........test2_date.txt
```

and if I add an other test1.txt like:

```
boite_noire/
helloworld/
....test1/
........test1_date.txt
....test2/
........test2_date.txt
....test1.txt
```

The next time I run the script:

```
boite_noire/
helloworld/
....test1/
........test1_date.txt
........test1_date.txt
....test2/
........test2_date.txt
```

I wrote this script :

[image: script]

But `os.walk` read files in directories and then create a directory named as the file, and I don't want that :(

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Add your code as text not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through each file and move it into the correct directory. This will work on a linux system (not sure about Windows - maybe better to use the **shutil.move** command).

```
import os
import time

d = 'www/boite_noire'

date = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
filesAll = os.listdir(d)
filesValid= [i for i in filesAll if i[-4:]=='.txt']

for f in filesValid:

    newName = f[:-4]+'_'+date+'.txt'
    try:
        os.mkdir('{0}/{1}'.format(d, f[:-4]))
    except:
        print 'Directory {0}/{1} already exists'.format(d, f[:-4])
    os.system('mv {0}/{1} {0}/{2}/{3}'.format(d, f, f[:-4], newName))
```

This is what the code is doing:

- Find all file in a specified directory
- Check the extension is *.txt*
- For each valid file:

  - Create a new name by appending the date/time
  - Create the directory if it exists
  - move the file into the directory (changing the name as it is moved)

Comment: Nice it works perfectly just a little problem is: if the directory already exist i would add the file in the directory (with the old one)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but do you know how i can change your script to do the same but now i have files named .txt and .bin ?